# Editing the DNS records to receive emails into two email hosting providors?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I have a website and I tried to configure my domain to work my email on Outlook so that I can have my email addresses with my own domain. This worked sucessfully for me.

I had two scenarios:

**Scenario 1**

Outlook required that I set my MX settings as follows:

```
DNS record type: MX
Host: mydomain.com
MX server: 1234567890123456789.pamx1.hotmail.com
TTL: 14400
Priority: 10 (or High priority)
```

This worked for me!

**Scenario 2**

```
DNS record type: MX
Host: mydomain.com
MX server: mail.mydomain.com
TTL: 14400
Priority: 0
```

Then I used the forwarding option in cPanel to my gmail and this worked.

I want both scenarios to work together i.e. when someone sends me an email on email@mydomain.com I want it to go both to my 'Outlook' email and to my 'Gmail' email.

When I tried to use them the two together and what I had in mind didn't work. Likewise I changed the priority for Scenario 1 to Priority:0 (as in scenario 2).

Only the solution in scenario 2 worked. Is it possible to have what I have in mind in place i.e. receiving emails in both scenario 1 and 2 simultaneously? If yes, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible to do that with DNS.  You must pick the one you want to be primary and that's where the mail will go.

In DNS, you can have one server act as a backup for the other, but it would only actually deliver to one or the other.

You could however have the primary mailserver forward the message to the secondary server.

One other option is you may be able to have gmail act as a pop/imap client and connect to the outlook server to retrieve the messages.